# Challenge with making full-page-background-image

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I am having difficulty making an image fill up the browser screen. I have a good sense of the problem, but I don't have an idea of how to solve the problem. If I do the following the image works great:

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file - Works with no problem**

```
   <body>
    <section id="home">
      <div class="home-content text-center">
        <div class="container">
          <h2>Headline for Website</h2>
          <div>
            <%= link_to "Button", "#", class: "btn btn-success" %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
```

**CSS File - Works with no problem**

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
body { 
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
#home {
  background-color: #444;
  background-position: center 0%;
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url('showcase-1.jpg');
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 1;
}
.home-content {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

The **PROBLEM** is that I need my app to be more dynamic. I need the app/views/layouts/application.html.erb to incorporate code from other pages. The code below in application.html.erb does show the content of other pages, but the image doesn't span the browser window as it did when I had the code directly in the file application.html.erb. Below is the code for the two files that creates my problem.

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file - Image doesn't cover background**

```
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  <div id="main">
   <%= yield %>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

The problem is that now the image does not cover the background. I am using the same code as above in a different html file. The homepage.html.erb file is being shown, but the image is not spanning the whole screen.

**app/views/pages/homepage.html.erb file - Image doesn't cover background**

```
<section id="home">
  <div class="home-content text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Header for Website</h2>
      <div>
        <%= link_to "Button", "#", class: "btn btn-success" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**What should I do? Do I need to change the CSS file? Do I need to change one of the HTML files?** Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If it isn't spanning the screen.. what IS it doing?  Your code seems like it should work unless you have something else interfering (other css)

Comment: The image spans the width of the screen, but the height of the image is about 100px.